# convert the value of one column into different ordered columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
ID PRO POS
1  A   1
1  B   2
1  C   3
1  D   4
2  A   1
2  B   2
2  C   3
3  A   1
3  B   2
```

For each ID, I would like to get the position columns into different columns, and copy the value of PRO to its corresponding column which will be in this format:

```
ID PRO POS 1 2 3 4
1  A   1   A B C D
1  B   2   A B C D
1  C   3   A B C D
1  D   4   A B C D
2  A   1   A B C NA
2  B   2   A B C NA
2  C   3   A B C NA
3  A   1   A B NA NA
3  B   2   A B NA NA
```

What is the optimal way in doing this in R, without writing many `ifelse` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`. We can spread the data frame and the join to the original data frame. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  spread(POS, PRO) %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = "ID")
dat2
#   ID PRO POS 1 2    3    4
# 1  1   A   1 A B    C    D
# 2  1   B   2 A B    C    D
# 3  1   C   3 A B    C    D
# 4  1   D   4 A B    C    D
# 5  2   A   1 A B    C <NA>
# 6  2   B   2 A B    C <NA>
# 7  2   C   3 A B    C <NA>
# 8  3   A   1 A B <NA> <NA>
# 9  3   B   2 A B <NA> <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID PRO POS

1  A   1
                  1  B   2
                  1  C   3
                  1  D   4
                  2  A   1
                  2  B   2
                  2  C   3
                  3  A   1
                  3  B   2",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: super cool solution, thank you. Do you know of any 'good' tutorial on tidyverse?

Comment: @ifreak https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tidyverse-tutorial-r

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion using `data.table`

```
rbindlist(
    DT[, .(.(cbind(ID, .SD, t(structure(PRO, names=POS))))), by=ID]$V1, 
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

#   ID PRO POS 1 2  3  4
#1:  1   A   1 A B  C  D
#2:  1   B   2 A B  C  D
#3:  1   C   3 A B  C  D
#4:  1   D   4 A B  C  D
#5:  2   A   1 A B  C NA
#6:  2   B   2 A B  C NA
#7:  2   C   3 A B  C NA
#8:  3   A   1 A B NA NA
#9:  3   B   2 A B NA NA
```

The equivalent in base is

```
rbindlist(
    by(DT, DT$ID, function(x) cbind(x, t(structure(x$PRO, names=x$POS)))),
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID PRO POS
1  A   1
1  B   2
1  C   3
1  D   4
2  A   1
2  B   2
2  C   3
3  A   1
3  B   2")
```

Comment: the data.table based solution looks interesting, but more complicated than the tidyverse one. Can you please explain the code a bit?

Comment: added the equivalent in base. hth. you can write www's method in data.table syntax as well